# Displaying Models in OpenGL C++

Tags: c++, object, opengl, models

|Actually, I am trying to display two or more models on the screen at the same time. I am generating three different vertex buffers for vertices, colors, normals separately, here is the main code:

```
    //==================From here is my implementation ==========================//

        // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders. Todo: load shader
        GLuint programID = LoadShaders("simple_shading.vertexshader", "simple_shading.fragmentshader");

        // Get a handle for uniform variables such as matrices, lights, ....
        GLuint ModelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ModelMatrix");
        GLuint ViewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ViewMatrix");
        GLuint NormalMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "NormalMatrix");
        GLuint lightPosition_worldspaceID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "lightPosition_worldspace");
        GLuint lightColorID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "lightColor");

        // Get a handle for vertex attribute arrays such as vertex positions, colors, normals, ....
        GLuint vertexPosition_modelspaceID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexPosition_modelspace");
        GLuint vertexColorID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexColor");
        GLuint vertexNormal_modelspaceID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexNormal_modelspace");

        // Load your scene


        TRIModel model;
        TRIModel model2;
    model.loadFromFile("models/ball.tri");
        model2.loadFromFile("models/ball.tri");
        //vector<TRIModel> models;



        /*** Here shows an exmple which generates three different vertex buffers for vertices, colors, normals.***/
        //However, you can always incorporate them together in a single buffer.(Hint: use glBufferSubData)

        GLuint vertexbuffer;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.vertices.size() * sizeof(vec3), &model.vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLuint colorbuffer;
        glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.vertices.size() * sizeof(vec3), &model.foreColors[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLuint normalbuffer;
        glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.vertices.size() * sizeof(vec3), &model.normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        ///*** **/

        GLfloat rotZ;
   while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
                glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //      //Tell OpenGL to use the shader program
                glUseProgram(programID);

        //      //send matrix to shader: You can use the keyboard and mouse to close the window and control the transformation
        //      //                               (See computeMatricesFromKey(window) )

                mat4 ModelMatrix;
                mat4 ViewMatrix = lookAt( vec3(0.5, 0.5, 1), vec3(2, 3, 2), vec3(0, 1.0, 0.0) );

                //move object to the world origin
        ModelMatrix = translate(mat4(1.0), -vec3(model.center[0], model.center[1], model.center[2]));
                ModelMatrix = scale( ModelMatrix, vec3(0.002, 0.002, 0.002) );
        ModelMatrix = rotate( ModelMatrix, rotZ, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0) );

                mat4 NormalMatrix = transpose( inverse(ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix) );
                glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);
                glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
                glUniformMatrix4fv(NormalMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &NormalMatrix[0][0]);

        //      //send lights to shader
                vec3 lightPosition = vec3(4, 4, 4);
                vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                glUniform3f(lightPosition_worldspaceID, lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z);
                glUniform3f(lightColorID, lightColor.r, lightColor.g, lightColor.b);

                //define an vertex attribute array on the vertex buffer
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexPosition_modelspaceID);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                        vertexPosition_modelspaceID, // The attribute we want to configure
                        3,                  // size
                        GL_FLOAT,           // type
                        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                        0,                  // stride
                        (void*) 0           // array buffer offset
                );

        //      //define an vertex attribute array on the color buffer
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorID);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                        vertexColorID, // The attribute we want to configure
                        3,                  // size
                        GL_FLOAT,           // type
                        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                        0,                  // stride
                        (void*) 0           // array buffer offset
                );

        //      //define an vertex attribute array on the normal buffer
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexNormal_modelspaceID);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                        vertexNormal_modelspaceID, // The attribute we want to configure
                        3,                  // size
                        GL_FLOAT,           // type
                        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                        0,                  // stride
                        (void*) 0           // array buffer offset
                );


                //draw the scene by vertex attribute arrays
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.vertices.size());
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexPosition_modelspaceID);
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorID);
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexNormal_modelspaceID);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        //     
        //      //update rotate angle
                rotZ += 0.1;
   }
        //// Cleanup VBO and shade      //glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
        glDeleteProgram(programID);



    //=================== implementation Ends here ================================//
```

I read in some resources that I can incorporate them together in a single buffer using glBufferSubData, but I dont know how to use it. eventually, I have successfully displayed one model as shown in the picture. Now, if I need to display another model, lets say I want to display another ball on the right side, what should I do? I tried to generate a nother set of buffers , but it is still not working. what I can see is just model one. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see the point of a down vote on this question.

Comment: There might be all kinds of "gotchas" in this scenario - I`ve had my fair share of frustrating all night long sessions with OpenGL only to find out I was making a stupid mistake. Ask yourself and check the following - The matrices passed in for scaling and transformation, try drawing the second model by itself and see if it displays ok by itself, try running your app under gDebugger and checking the data in your buffers etc. Good luck!